# Iterate or loop through DataFrame with function and counter

Tags: python, pandas, math

how can I iterate through the rows and check if a value is double size (or more) or half size (or less) than his neighbor and count this number for each row ind store in variable `count`? For example here is my dataframe. In the second row you can say 4 is the half (or less) or the double or more than 6? Answer: NO, so `count = 0.`

And then you check 6 is the half (or less) or the double or more than 1? Answer:YES, so `count = 1`.

```
A B C
1 0 1
4 6 1
3 3 3
5 0 0
```

Here is the code

```
import math
import pandas as pd
data = {'A':[1,4,3,5],'B':[0,6,3,0],'C':[1,1,3,0]} #sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to iterate, that will be very slow. Here's a vectorized solution by comparing vectors with `shift`, `mul` and `div`

```
df2 = df.shift(axis=1) # shift the values one place to compare
m1 = df >= df2.mul(2) # values which are double or more
m2 = df <= df2.div(2) # values which are half or less

counts = (m1|m2).sum(axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
0    2
1    1
2    0
3    2
dtype: int64
```

---

**Step by step**:

Shifting values one place to the right to compare:

```
df.shift(axis=1)

    A    B    C
0 NaN  1.0  0.0
1 NaN  4.0  6.0
2 NaN  3.0  3.0
3 NaN  5.0  0.0
```

Comparing which value is double or more his neighbour:

```
df >= df2.mul(2)

       A      B      C
0  False  False   True
1  False  False  False
2  False  False  False
3  False  False   True
```

Comparing which value is half or less his neighbour:

```
df <= df2.div(2)

       A      B      C
0  False   True  False
1  False  False   True
2  False  False  False
3  False   True   True
```

Finally getting the count where comparison one **or** two is `True`:

*notice that `|` is the `or` operator in `pandas`*

```
m1|m2

       A      B      C
0  False   True   True
1  False  False   True
2  False  False  False
3  False   True   True
```

Comment: I don't really understand the first step. Do you compare the first value of B with first value of C and so on?

Comment: Yes we do, we shift the values on step to the right and then compare them the original value. In this case, column C has no value to compare on the right, so that's why we dont see it in `df2`

Comment: Yes that makes sense right? There's no value on the left of column `A` to "come in his place". Just do `print(df)` and `print(df2)` and if you look at it, it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Erfan's answer is correct, and far better than iteration because vectorizing the operation allows you to leverage the power of efficient compiled code in pandas and numpy to calculate things like this much more quickly with less memory consumption.

However, iteration can be done if necessary using `iterrows()` and `iteritems()`, and the indexes can be used to compare to nearby values.

```
import math
import pandas as pd
data = {'A':[1,4,3,5],'B':[0,6,3,0],'C':[1,1,3,0]} #sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

for rindex, row in df.iterrows():
    for cindex, value, in row.iteritems():
        print("row", rindex, "column ", cindex, "value ", value)
```

I'll not take the time to type out a full answer because the vectorized solution is better in every way for this application.